# Jquery Function works on Local Server but not on Live?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am stuck with a little problem that i have drop down horizontal menu bar and i have applied jquery functions to open and close Parent and child items.
So fat its works fine on my local server but it is not working on my live server.Every thing is uploaded on live and I have checked my references of all script files many times from live server.

here is my HTML
References :

```
    <script src="../../resources/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   </script>
    <script src="../../resources/scripts/smooth.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

HTML Code :

```
 <div id="menu">
                    <ul id="Ul2" class="opened">
                        <li class="collapsible"><a href="#" class="collapsible plus">Settings</a>
                            <ul id="Ul3" class="collapsed">
                                <li><a href="#">General Settings</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="Ul4" class="opened">
                        <li class="collapsible"><a href="#" class="collapsible plus">Email Templates</a>
                            <ul id="Ul5" class="collapsed">
                                <li><a href="#">All Email Templates</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Add Email Template</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="Ul6" class="opened">
                        <li class="collapsible"><a href="#" class="collapsible plus">City</a>
                            <ul id="Ul7" class="collapsed">
                                <li><a href="#">All Cities</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Add City</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

here is my Script :

```
$("#menu li a[class~=collapsible]").click(function () {
        var element = $(this);

        if (element.attr("class") == "collapsible plus") {
            element.attr("class", "collapsible minus");
        } else {
            element.attr("class", "collapsible plus");
        }

        var list = element.next();

        if (list.attr("class") == "collapsed") {
            list.attr("class", "expanded");
        } else {
            list.attr("class", "collapsed");
        }
    });
```

[Click here](http://pakistantransporters.com/project/CMS/Hotels.aspx) to see my site on live so you can easily check problem why script is not calling on live.

Comment: your js path is not loading library <script src="../../resources/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   </script>     http://pakistantransporters.com/resources/scripts/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js   not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recomend you to do not to use relative path like:

```
   ../../resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
```

just use browser-reachable Url like:

```
yourdomaain.com/resources/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js
```

or just put your assets inside webroot. It's not useful to put your assets(css, js, img) outside webroot, If you want to display them to everyone, then each asset must be reachable by everyone too;

Comment: I have do according to your instructions but still unable to call jquery function... please check my site again.

Answer (score 2):

It's due to **all** of your JavaScript files giving a 404 error message and so all of your JS isn't working. You can see this in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all your js including `http://pakistantransporters.com/resources/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js` shows 404 not found.

Comment: Install Firebug for Firefox, you can see it there. Or Google Developer console, or IE Developer console.

Comment: Use chrome browser to access machine - press `F12` click on console in the developer bar window.

Answer (score 0):

This is because so many of your URLs point to nowhere (404 not found), including the jQuery reference - so jQuery isn't loaded, and your script tries to use it, which fails with `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

You need to fix your paths, firstly.

Comment: i have put exact references in solution, but still unreachable to solution :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you either have :-

1) Not uploaded script folder on server.

2) Your javascript files have wrong path.

3) Your script folder don't have read permission.

Answer (score 0):

First download the jquery relative version into in your local then you use it.

lick:- xpath/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause for such a problem is referring to an `http` jQuery JavaScript file from an `https`-hosted HTML file.

Wrong:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Right:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is an issue you have seen or used but in asp.net core there is 
`<environment include="Development">` inside the layout it ruined my deploy before just if you see it i wanted to write that to here. Do not forget about it if you use. 
You can see more about it [here](https://scottsauber.com/2017/07/19/environment-taghelper-exclude-and-include-attributes-in-asp-net-core-2/).

Answer (score 0):

try to check if the link starts with "http" instead of "https".. this happens when you open the link of jquery in new tab, 'https' change to 'http'